# Solar panel, estimate power in various illuminating conditions

Tags: solar-cell

I'm trying to estimate available power from a solar cell like this one **PRT-13781**
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13781

Includes:

```
1x Solar Panel - 2W
1x Barrel Plug Adapter - 3.5mm to 5.5mm
```

Features:

```
Monocrystalline cells - 19% efficient
Open Circuit Voltage: 7.0V
Peak Voltage: 6.0V
Peak Current: 378mA
Peak Power: 2.27 Watts
Four screws on back corners of panel allow multiple mounting options
Waterproof Urethane Coating
UV Resistant
```

Obviously, the 2W will be obtained in ideal conditions, clear sky, sunny, etc and at MPPT point.

How can I estimate available power for cloudy days, (variation with temperature will be also nice to know) etc. I cannot find relevant documents to start with, however, I will do at some point some measurements.

Until then, I am looking to best effort estimate just to have a start point in choosing the DC/DC MPPT charger, discharging the battery in my actual load conditions, etc.

For example this post question almost the same
[How to estimate solar panel output as a function of solar radiation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175200/how-to-estimate-solar-panel-output-as-a-function-of-solar-radiation)

but no relevant calculation based on illumination (lux) or percent of rated illumination vs. generated power.

EDITED
We can close this question, I finally found a **very well documented answer** here
[How do I define solar irradiance in the context of a solar cell?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/how-do-i-define-solar-irradiance-in-the-context-of-a-solar-cell)

Thanks user @Russell McMahon

Comment: You need to check out weather patterns, days of cloud cover, hours of sunshine and statistics :  see the Weibull distribution ...

Comment: Yes, I'll do that for a specific location. But I have a sensor that could be mounted on a building with no direct sunlight due to mechanical reasons. So I'll prefer a estimation based on illumination somehow and not the weather directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about average weather conditions pertaining the where the op lives.

Comment: Your output is Directly tied to the weather, whether you like it or not....

Comment: Edited for more clarity